# How much richer is the average member of the US Congress than the average professional in their district?

Tags: united-states, congress, inequality

This is a multipart question, but it is seeking to generally understand if the average member of Congress is able to improve his lot financially by entering public service.  My experience is that it is not, but I'd like to find some numbers.

Specifically, I'd like to know the following:

1. How much is a Representative and/or Senator paid?
2. How does that compare to the average executive or business owner in the US? (These are successful people after all?)
3. What is the average Net Worth of a member of Congress vs. the average net worth of a college educated American?
4. What proportion of members of Congress are millionaires or billionaires?

Comment: +1, well posed question. This site might be useful for any potential answerer: http://ballotpedia.org/Net_worth_of_United_States_Senators_and_Representatives

Comment: Partial answer to #4: 52% of congress are millionaires http://www.opensecrets.org/news/2014/01/millionaires-club-for-first-time-most-lawmakers-are-worth-1-million-plus/

Comment: #2 is tricky in that I don't know if you can find exact statistics. Many people own many companies, some if which don't make any money (sometimes intentionally)

Comment: Partial answer to #3: Congress had a median net worth of $1,008,767. http://ballotpedia.org/Changes_in_Net_Worth_of_U.S._Senators_and_Representatives_(Personal_Gain_Index)

Comment: #1 should be straightforward.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salaries_of_members_of_the_United_States_Congress) says $174,000, unless you hold one of the top positions.

Comment: #3 should really be split into "money inherited/earned before Congress" vs "money after"

Comment: Questions should be split.

Comment: #2 may also be too broad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How much is a Representative and/or Senator paid?

Both [US Representatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_of_Representatives#Salary_and_benefits) and [US Senators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate#Salary_and_benefits) receive a base salary of $174,000 plus benefits. The Speaker of the House receives $223,500, and the President *pro tem* of the Senate and majority and minority leaders in both houses receive $193,400.

> How does that compare to the average executive or business owner in the US?

I don't know of any way to calculate 'average business owner'. This is too broad of a definition and fraught with other complexities (such as does the owner even draw a salary?). Plus, I'm not sure if there is a strong correlation between a business owner and a member of congress.

Some possible stats that might work for comparison:

- [median household income as of 2011](http://www.mybudget360.com/how-much-do-americans-earn-what-is-the-average-us-income/):  $50,502
- [median individual annual wage](http://www.mybudget360.com/how-much-do-americans-earn-what-is-the-average-us-income/): $26,695
- [Average annual salary of a US College grad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_income_in_the_United_States): $45,400
- [Average annual salary of a US College grad with a professional degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_income_in_the_United_States): $99,300

> What is the average Net Worth of a member of Congress vs. the average net worth of a college educated American?

[The median net worth of a member of congress](http://www.opensecrets.org/news/2014/01/millionaires-club-for-first-time-most-lawmakers-are-worth-1-million-plus/): $1,008,767

[The median net worth of a college graduate (household) in the US](http://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/bulletin/2012/pdf/scf12.pdf): $195,200*

* Note that this stat is kind of hard to find. That number is from page 17 of the referenced PDF report. Also note that that is a household number where the head is a college grad.

> What proportion of members of Congress are millionaires or billionaires?

Per the aforementioned article referencing the median net worth of a member of congress, 52% have a net worth over 1 million dollars.

I believe that the percentage of billionaires in congress is 0%. As of 2010, Darrell Issa was the wealthiest in congress with a [net worth of only 700 million](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2012-02-26/china-s-billionaire-lawmakers-make-u-s-peers-look-like-paupers).

Comment: Nice job pulling all this together.  It might be in the spirit of the question to compare these numbers to company CEOs (even though they aren't *owners*, per se).  I don't know if there's any more on that than there is on owner salaries, though.

Comment: @Bobson the one number that stood out to me was the % of millionaires. In congress, it's 52%. In the US as a whole, it's 1%. Not sure if that means anything, but was interesting.

Comment: Also, there's a cap on outside earned income: they can't make more than 15% of their congressional pay from work done for outside entities (including speeches).

Comment: @cpast that is true but a bit of a red herring. They can't make more than 15% in outside *wages* but there's no limit to earnings form investments and dividends: http://www.newsmax.com/US/Congress-outside-income-triples/2011/09/19/id/411537/

Comment: @DA. that's why I said "from _work_ done for outside entities."

Comment: @cpast that's where it comes down to semantics. Is sitting on a board of directors 'work'? I guess not according to the rules.

Comment: @DA. No member or senior staff of either house can serve on a board for _any_ pay besides travel reimbursement and insurance (which is treated as a gift). In the Senate, Senators and anyone employed at least 90 days at >=$25k can't serve on _any_ board (even for free) unless it's a 501(c) nonprofit or mostly serves Senate employees and their families (even then, there are strict conflict-of-interest rules). Sources: [1](http://www.ethics.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/conflictsofinterest), [2](http://ethics.house.gov/outside-employment-income/restrictions-outside-employment#emp_serving_board)

Comment: @cpast, ah, yes. You are correct. You can't get paid for sitting on a board of directors. Though it looks like you can get paid for owning businesses...as long as it's not a salary, I guess.